# Self Study Qn on Exponential Distribution

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution

I am currently working on a self-study question relating to exponential distribution. I made an attempt but was not able to make sense of the answer. When I looked up the reference guide, it offered the answer at 0.1068.

Appreciate any guidance and advice on where has my method gone wrong. Many thanks.

***Question***

> When a truck arrives at a checkpoint, each truck will be checked by customs agents. The times are exponentially distributed with a service rate of 10 trucks per hour. What is the probability that a truck requires less than 15 minutes but more than 10 minutes to be checked?

***Attempt***

[image]

Comment: Replace lambda value with 1/6 instead of 6 which is the mean. Wrong formula corresponds to wrong result!

Comment: @Epaminondas Thanks for the enlightenment. Clearly a very careless mistake by me. Thank you so much. I was wondering if you will be able to add your comment as an answer so that I may mark it as the answer to my question and give due credit? Thanks

Comment: With great pleasure. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Replace lambda value with 1/6 instead of 6 which is the mean. Wrong formula corresponds to wrong result!